# Unused node detected when configuring email publisher for CruiseControl.NET 1.4.2

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, email-publisher

I am trying to configure my CruiseControl.NET server to send emails to those the contribute to the source; however, I cannot seem to configure the email publisher properly.  I am receiving the following error from CruiseControl.NET.

> Exception: Unused node detected: <subjectSettings><subject buildResult="Success" value="Build Successful! Have a cookie!"/></subjectSettings>

This is my configuration.  The real email addresses have been altered to protect the innocent.

```
<publishers>
    <xmllogger />

    <email from="abs@companyx.com" mailhost="email.companyx.com" includeDetails="true" >
        <users>
            <user name="john@companyx.com" group="buildMasters" address="john@companyx.com"/>
            <user name="jane@companyx.com" group="buildMasters" address="jane@companyx.com"/>
            <user name="joe@companyx.com" group="developers" address="joe@companyx.com"/>
            <user name="jill@companyx.com" group="developers" address="jill@companyx.com"/>
            <user name="jerry@companyx.com" group="developers" address="jerry@companyx.com"/>
        </users>
        <groups>
            <group name="buildMasters" notification="always"/>
            <group name="developers" notification="change"/>
        </groups>
        <modifierNotificationTypes>
            <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Success</NotificationType>
        </modifierNotificationTypes>
        <subjectSettings>
                <subject buildResult="Success" value="Build Successful! Have a cookie!" />
        </subjectSettings>
    </email>

</publishers>
```

How can I properly configure the email publisher to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you building CruiseControl from scratch? because it looks like that functionality was only checked in a few weeks ago, and if you are using one of the releases that functionality isn't in there.

Comment: I am using precompiled binaries (v. 1.4.2). I thought this might have  been the case. The online documentation was not very clear on which version it applied to; however, the installed documentation does not describe this functionality so it must be absent in the version I have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I came upon this question running version 1.4.4 and receiving publisher errors similar to this:

> unused node detected notification="always"

I was using the [Email Publisher](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Email%20Publisher.html) documentation and couldn't figure out the problem.  Turns out there's an error in the documentation; under the groups block `notification` has been changed to `notifications`.  The groups block should now read:

```
<groups>
    <group name="buildMasters" notifications="always"/>
    <group name="developers" notifications="change"/>
</groups>
```

Comment: Wow...  I can't believe that they changed "notification" to "notifications".  That extra "s" in the config solved my issue though.  Thanks!